# How to run a function every x minutes in react

Tags: reactjs

My users have the option to run a function every minute, every two minutes or turn it off, altogether, it looks like this...

```
<select value={runFunctionTime} onChange={e => setRunFunctionTime(e.target.value)}>
  <option value='off'>Off</option>
  <option value='one minute'>One Minute</option>
  <option value='two minutes'>Two Minutes</option>
</select>
```

This then updates the state. My question is, how do I run a function every x minutes with x being the value they select, if they turn it 'off' then I don't want the function to run at all.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        let reload = 60

        const autoRefresh = setTimeout(() => {
            if(autoRefreshTime === 'off'){
                reload = 0
            } else if(autoRefreshTime === 'one minute'){
                reload = 60
                RunFunction()
            } else if(autoRefreshTime === 'two minutes'){
                reload = 120
                RunFunction()
            }
        }, reload * 1000)
    })
```

This didn't work, so does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most probably because `autoRefreshTime` is not in useEffect dependencies.

Also set reload time outside of timeout's callback, everything in that callback is called after the reload time

This should help, so useEffect knows it should refresh every time `autoRefreshTime` is changed

```
useEffect(() => {
        let reload = 0

        if(autoRefreshTime === 'one minute'){
            reload = 60
        } else if(autoRefreshTime === 'two minutes'){
            reload = 120
        }

        if (!reload) {
            return
        }

        const autoRefresh = setInterval(() => {
            RunFunction()
        }, reload * 1000)

       return () => {
          // Clear previous timeout
          clearInterval(autoRefresh)
       }
}, [autoRefreshTime])
```

Comment: I need it to run every x minutes though, so how would I make this happen? as I think your code stops once it's ran once doesn't it

Comment: Oh right, my bad. Just use setInterval instead of setTimeout and clearInterval instead of clearTimeout

Comment: I added an if statement inside the setInterval to prevent it running when set to 'off'

Comment: Should be fixed, it will escape function if reload is 0